# Android Line Drawing application

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-canvas, android-drawable

Android application used to draw lines using buttons from layout. How can I set the color and thickness of line at run time? Please help me with this application

Answer (score 0):

```
<View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="#001155"
        android:setvisibility="GONE"
        android:id="@+id/divd"
        android:layout_marginRight="45dp"/>
```

it will draw line but invisible you can set visibility on button click
and also can change color from java class

Answer (score 0):

```
     GradientDrawable border = new GradientDrawable();
     border.setColor(0xFFFFFFFF); //white background
     border.setStroke(4, Color.BLUE); //black border with full opacity              
     if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            view.setBackgroundDrawable(border);
     }
     else{
             view.setBackground(border);}
```

You can set this drawable on runtime , view will updated based on your requirement.